# AutoTask API, How to query Entity from Autotask API by using User Defined Field (UDF)

Tags: soap, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to pull some `Account`entities from Autotask database using a WebAPI.
Instead of querying by `ID` field I need to pull it using a UDF `"Next Visit"`, which is of type **Date**.

I've stated the function/query being used. Now as stated in the API Document

> To specify that a field is a UDF, you must add udf="true" within the field tag. You
>   can only specify **one UDF field per query**.

I'm still getting ResponseCode = -1, with error message `"Unable to find next visit in the Account Entity. "`

```
public static Account[] getAccountsWithNextVisitDueIn(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
    {
        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
        query.Append("<queryxml><entity>Account</entity>");
        query.Append("<query><condition operator=\"and\"> ");
        query.Append("<field udf=\"true\">Next Visit<expression op=\"greaterthanorequals\">" + fromDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyy") + "</expression></field>");
        query.Append("<field udf=\"true\">Next Visit<expression op=\"lessthan\">" + toDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyy") + "</expression></field>");
        query.Append("</condition></query></queryxml>");

        ATWSResponse response = connHandler.Query(query.ToString());

        if(connHandler.Success(response))
        {
            Entity[] accountEntities = response.EntityResults;
            Account[] accounts = Array.ConvertAll(accountEntities, item => (Account)item);

            return accounts;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the command GetFieldInfo to review the list of UserDefinedFields for the Account entity. Be sure that the field name is *exactly* what you are using in your query.

If you're not sure, then paste the output of GetFieldInfo for Account here.

Comment: Thanks Travis, i'm actually getting the Accounts back if i put only one expression without using the condition element. But i want to pull Accounts between a given range of 'Next Visit'. This requires UDF 'Next Visit' to be mentioned twice in the query and it get failed as Autotask limits use of single UDF per query. It fails with error stating "More then one UDF in xmlquery". Any idea how should i do it ?

Comment: Ahhhh, I see. Sorry about that. The only way to do that is to filter using the API for the "greater than" part, and then filter the result set on your client-side later to filter out the stuff that is "less than". If that UDF is not used for most accounts, you could also query the API where "Next Visit" is not null, and then do your filtering client-side.

Comment: Ohoo... No, 'Next Visit' is the determining field used for all the Accounts to filter them.

Comment: Then I would filter for either GreaterThan or LessThan only (whichever will return the least amount of results), and then filter again in your code to complete the query. Don't forget that the API only returns 500 results at a time, so you will need to repeat your query and add "ID > x" (where x is the highest ID you've received) until you receive no results.